# Xelatex vs Lualatex and font substitution

Tags: xetex, luatex, substitution

As is known, in the Turkish language the `i` exists as distinct letters in two versions, with and without a dot (with very different pronunciations): the dotted couple `i / İ` and the dotless couple `ı / I`.

Plz, consider this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\usepackage{fontspec}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\ifluatex
\usepackage[turkish,italian]{babel}
\babelfont[italian]{rm}[Ligatures=TeX]{Garamond Premier Pro}
\babelfont[turkish]{rm}[Ligatures=TeX]{Garamond Premier Pro}
\fi

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\ifxetex
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Garamond Premier Pro}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
\setotherlanguage{turkish}
\fi

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\textbf{Italian}

\verb!\MakeUppercase{aabbccddiixx}! \MakeUppercase{aabbccddiixx}

\verb!\MakeUppercase{aabbccddııxx}! \MakeUppercase{aabbccddııxx}

\verb!\MakeLowercase{AABBCCDDİİ}! \MakeLowercase{AABBCCDDİİ}

\verb!\MakeLowercase{AABBCCDDII}! \MakeLowercase{AABBCCDDII}

fi ffi

\textbf{Turkish}

\selectlanguage{turkish}

\verb!\MakeUppercase{aabbccddiixx}! \MakeUppercase{aabbccddiixx}

\verb!\MakeUppercase{aabbccddııxx}! \MakeUppercase{aabbccddııxx}

\verb!\MakeLowercase{AABBCCDDİİ}! \MakeLowercase{AABBCCDDİİ}

\verb!\MakeLowercase{AABBCCDDII}! \MakeLowercase{AABBCCDDII}

fi ffi

\end{document}
```

If you compile with Xelatex all substitution work fine.
But if you compile with Lualatex, two `i` disappear:

[image]

What does this different behavior depend on?
Is there a solution with Lualatex?
I can also modify some lookups of the font, but I must first understand the reasons for what happens.

Thank you

**Postscriptum 1st August**

I realize that there is a new version of turkish.ldf (2019/07/05 v1.4), but compiling the same file I receive:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/locale/tr/babel-turkish.t
ex

! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.13 \StartBabelCommands
                      *{turkish}{}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.14   \SetCase

? 
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
\relax 
l.15     {\uccode`i=
                  `İ\relax
? 
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
\relax 
l.16      \uccode`ı=
                   `I\relax}
? 
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
\relax 
l.17     {\lccode`İ=
                   `i\relax
? 
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
\relax 
l.18      \lccode`I=
                  `ı\relax}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.19   \SetHyphenMap
                  {%
? 

! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.22 \EndBabelCommands
```

Giving ENTER every time, finally it compiles... 
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I can reproduce the issue with other fonts, so I don't think it is an issue with the font itself.

Comment: I didn't mean to report the problem to that font, mine was just a MWE. But obviously there is a different general behavior in handlign even substitutions in Xelatex and Lualatex. Which the respective logic? Why does Lualatex fail ?

Comment: Turns out is not a LuaTeX vs XeTeX but a babel vs. polyglossia issue, c.f. https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/18.

Comment: You shouldn't edit your question like this. Better ask a new question. But beside this: I don't get the error. Delete your auxiliary files (aux, toc etc) and try again. If the error persists show the complete log-file.

Answer (score 5):

`turkish.ldf` is broken: it is too old and doesn't take into account that the encoding for lualatex has changed from EU2 to TU.

In two places `EU1 EU2` in the ldf must be changed to `TU`:

```
\StartBabelCommands*{turkish}{captions}
   [unicode, charset=utf8, fontenc=EU1 EU2] %<<< e.g. here
```

Notify the maintainer.

The alternative is to use the new babel interface and to load the language through an ini:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\usepackage{fontspec}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{babel}
\babelprovide[import=tr,main]{turkish}
\babelfont[turkish]{rm}[Ligatures=TeX]{arial}

\begin{document}
\textbf{Turkish}

aabbccddııxx AABBCCDDİİ

\verb!\MakeUppercase{aabbccddiixx}! \MakeUppercase{aabbccddiixx}

\verb!\MakeUppercase{aabbccddııxx}! \MakeUppercase{aabbccddııxx}

\verb!\MakeLowercase{AABBCCDDİİ}! \MakeLowercase{AABBCCDDİİ}

\verb!\MakeLowercase{AABBCCDDII}! \MakeLowercase{AABBCCDDII}

fi ffi

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Shouldn’t that be dotlessi in the last line?

Comment: @RalfStubner I don't know the exact rules. The uppercase command maps both to I, so it is not quite clear what the lowercase should do. But this could certainly be adapted.

Comment: Right, the uppercase command is probably also incorrect. AFAIK for Turkish the mapping should be `ı <-> I` and `i <-> İ`, i.e. the dotted and dotless variants do not mix. That's what one get's when compiling the OP's file with XeTeX.

Comment: Found the rules: See figures 5-14 and 5-15 in [5.18 Case Mappings](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode12.1.0/ch05.pdf#G21180).

Comment: @RalfStubner yes, looks like babel gets it wrong. It should be reported as an issue. https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues

Comment: Done: https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/18

Comment: The dotted i remains in uppercase and lowercase (for which i -> İ), and in the same way the dottless i remains such in uppercase and lowercase (so ı -> I).
Thanks for the clarification.
I see that there is a bug to be corrected ... and thanks for having already reported it

Comment: A fixed version is now available.

Comment: It gives me some errors. I report them above